# Remove tabBar indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to remove the tabBar indicator using the TabNavigator (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html) on react native.

Here are my tabBarOptions:

```
tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: ColorManager.colors.primaryColor,
    inactiveTintColor: ColorManager.colors.greyBlack,
    pressColor: ColorManager.colors.colorPress,
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: true,
    style: {
        backgroundColor: ColorManager.colors.fullWhite,
        elevation: 10,
        shadowColor: ColorManager.colors.greyBlack,
        shadowOpacity: .1
    }
}
```

the indicatorStyle property exists, but I don't know how to just remove the indicator.

Currently it looks like this (running on Android):

[image]

The indicator is the yellow part.

Comment: Can you try `indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: ColorManager.colors.primaryColor }`

Comment: Of course this code works and it will change the indicator color to primaryColor. I don't want to set the indicator to transparent, or set its opacity to 0. I want to completely remove the indicator, to remove the space between the icons and the bottom of the screen.

Comment: how about setting its height to 0 then?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the best solution, but it works. I'll let that for the moment. Thanks a lot, bennygenel.

Answer (score 2):

In your `tabBarOptions` object add in `indicatorStyle` and make it transparent:

```
indicatorStyle: {
   backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

To actually remove the indicator you would have to do a custom tabBar element, which you can do. Something like this:

```
import TabBarLib from 'react-navigation/src/views/TabView/TabBarTop'


class CustomTab extends Component { 
   render() {
        <TabBarLib {...this.props} style={[style, styles.tabBar]} indicatorStyle={[{backgroundColor:forecolor, height:3}, indicatorStyle]} activeTintColor={forecolor} inactiveTintColor={forecolor} renderIcon={this.renderIcon} />
   }
}
```

Then give this in your TabNavigator options in the `tabBarComponent` like this:

```
const HubNavigator = TabNavigator(
    TABS,
    {
        tabBarComponent: HubBar,
        initialRouteName: INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME,
        backBehavior: 'initialRoute',
        swipeEnabled: false,
        // lazy: true,
        tabBarComponent: HubBar,
```